# Why is my return not changing when the isLogin state changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-router-dom

I am making an `axios` call which verifies the token that I get from the localStorage and than I set the state based on the return of the call, but the state doesn't wait for the call to finish and renders with the default value of the state.

I tried this code but it isn't working.

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Protected = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLogin, setisLogin] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkLogin = async () => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('tkn');
      await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth', { token: token })
        .then((res) => {
          setisLogin(res.data.login)
          console.log(res.data.login);
        })
    };

    checkLogin()
  }, [])

  return (
    isLogin ? children : <Navigate to={'/'} />
  )
};
```

Comment: I think the problem is `<Navigate to={'/'} />`. By the time the response to the AJAX call comes in, the `Protected` has been unmounted.

Comment: What is this line `console.log(res.data.login);` logs?

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The issue is that the initial `isLogin` state value matches the "unauthenticated" state on the initial render cycle and the redirect is rendered. At the end of the initial render cycle the `useEffect` hook is called and the POST request is made, and state updated... but this is all too late, the navigation was already rendered and effected.

## Solution

Use an initial `isLogin` value that is neither `true` to mean a user is authenticated, nor `false` to mean a user is unauthenticated, and do an explicit check for this *third* case of "uncertainty" that conditionally ***doesn't*** render either of the `children` prop or the `Navigate` component.

Example:

```
const Protected = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(); // <-- initially undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkLogin = async () => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('tkn');
      const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth', { token });
      setIsLogin(res.data.login);
    };

    checkLogin();
  }, []);

  if (isLogin === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return isLogin ? children : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};
```